# How can i fill button in the container?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to fill the button in the rest empty of the container.
I've tried it with `display: table-cell;width: 100%;` but it's not working.

I use bootstrap 3 `btn-block` not working too.

I can set width with px for `<button>` but when i remove the <`div class="product-social-links">` i get again white pleace in the container.

Current state:
[image: Current state:]

What i want to do:
[image: What i want to do:]

```
<div class="product-info-actions">
    <div class="product-add-form">
        <form data-product-sku="24-UG01" action="xxxx" method="post" id="product_addtocart_form" novalidate="novalidate">                           
            <div class="box-tocart">
                <div class="fieldset">
                    <div class="field qty">
                        <label class="label" for="qty"><span>Qty</span></label>
                        <div class="control control-qty-cart">
                            <span class="quantity-controls quantity-minus"></span>
                            <span class="quantity-controls quantity-plus"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                        <div class="actions" style="font-size: 20px;">
                            <button type="submit" title="Add to Cart" class="action primary tocart" id="product-addtocart-button">
                                <span><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart" style="color: white;"></i>&nbsp;Add to Cart</span>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="product-social-links">
        <div class="product-addto-links" data-role="add-to-links">
            <a title="Add to Wish List" href="#" class="action towishlist" data-post="" data-action="add-to-wishlist">
                <span>Add to Wish List</span></a>
            <a title="Add to Compare" href="#" data-post="" data-role="add-to-links" class="action tocompare">
                <span>Add to Compare</span>
            </a>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "fill button". Your screenshot shows an element with the class "product-info-actions", but that element is not present in the HTML you share.

Comment: I updated it the code and added image.

Comment: Maybe you could provide css as it is a css problem

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
<button style="width:auto!important" type="submit" title="Add to Cart" class="action primary tocart" id="product-addtocart-button">
<span><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart" style="color: white;"></i>&nbsp;Add to Cart</span>
</button>
```

Try this new code, hopefully it works and then you can adjust the width as you like.

Comment: are you using bootstrap

Comment: Yes, but it may have been modified.

Comment: You can also learn the flex method, its quite easy and you could also get some live exmaple throught this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90178/make-a-div-fill-the-height-of-the-remaining-screen-space?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

It seems the div with class `fieldset` contains 2 divs:

- one with class `field qty` (has qty controller)
- other one with class `actions` (has add-to-cart button)

You can use flexbox to solve this scenario.

Steps to take:

(1) attach `display:flex` to `fieldset`

(2) attach `flex:1` to `actions`

(3) make the button inside `actions` div to be width 100% with `w-100` class

Could look like so:

```
<div class="fieldset" style="display:flex">
  <div class="field qty">
    <label class="label" for="qty"><span>Qty</span></label>
    <div class="control control-qty-cart">
      <span class="quantity-controls quantity-minus"></span>
      <span class="quantity-controls quantity-plus"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="actions" style="font-size: 20px; flex:1">
    <button type="submit" title="Add to Cart" class="action primary tocart w-100" id="product-addtocart-button">
      <span><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart" style="color: white"></i>&nbsp;Add to Cart</span>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

This will ensure that div with `actions` class expands to take as much space as is available (depending on device size) and that in turn will make the button take all the space.